# how to disable tomcat caching?

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

how to disable tomcat caching?
I use this -

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize ="0" cacheTTL="1">
```

in Tomcat/conf/context.xml

but it not helps

Comment: I think your question is missing a

Answer (score 13):

Actual problem is  `antiResourceLocking="true"`.

Looks like there is a conflict with `cachingAllowed="false"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're using, but in context.xml you can change the value of `cachingAllowed` by removing the flag.

**Remember to delete the cache folder after that.**

---

**Resources :**

- [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [How do I disable tomcat caching? I'm having weird static file problems.](https://serverfault.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-disable-tomcat-caching-im-having-weird-static-file-problems)

Comment: Often, it's a formatting problem in the question (the XML is there but not visible). Like in this case :)

Comment: @Pascal Thivent It explains a lot :)

Comment: I use these params 
antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true" cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize ="0" cacheTTL="1"

Comment: Like I said **Remember to delete the cache folder after that.**

Comment: actual problem were conflict with antiResourceLocking="true"

Answer (score 0):

cachingAllowed did not help. I resolved this by modifying :

```
    $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/thewebapp.xml
```

which is the cached file of context.xml

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your sever.xml file.

```
<Context className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext"
             cachingAllowed="false"
             charsetMapperClass="org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper"
             cookies="true" 
             reloadable="false" 
             wrapperClass="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper">
    </Context>
```

Make sure to delete all data from  /work/Catalina/localhost directory before restarting tomcat.
Also clear your browser cache.

Its a good practice to disable browser caching while your app is in development. 
This post may help [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)