# Tomcat can't see newly created static files and is server-side caching the old files

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, static-files

I use Tomcat 7 on Windows XP.

- I have a directory with static files (HTML, CSS, JS) in `%TOMCATDIR%/webapps/myapplication`.
- They're accessible via `localhost:8080/myapplication`

When a change happens to a file in my server dir, **it is not reflected:**

- modified files are returned (200 OK) the same as previously **(tested with Fiddler; for sure not a browser cache issue - cleared cache, using different browsers etc.)**,
- newly created files in that directory are not accessible (404).

The above happens no matter how many times I try to reload the file, or even add query string to it (`img.jpg?timestamp=...`).

In `%TOMCATDIR%/conf/context.xml` I've set various directives to disable server-side caching:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize="1" cacheTTL="1">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/40205/how-do-i-disable-tomcat-caching-im-having-weird-static-file-problems and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743136/how-to-disable-tomcat-caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be remove `antiResourceLocking="true"`.

If anyone's more knowledgable about the topic, or know how to workaround it other way, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Note that if you are uploading files into `webapps/myapplication`, you run the risk of Tomcat deleting all of them when you undeploy the webapp. You might want to look into the `aliases` feature of the `<Context>` element to "mount" directories outside of the deployment directory: these directories will not be deleted during an undeployment.

Comment: I don't mean the WAR that is being extracted to `myapplication`, but the folder I've created myself. In that situation, it shouldn't be ever removed by Tomcat I guess, right? Anyway, I don't develop directly in this folder, I do it in some other place and Eclipse FileSync plugin synchronizes from dev folder to server folder on file save. However I'll try to take a look at what you've written.

Comment: I mean that Tomcat deletes deployment directories (like `webapps/myapp`) on undeploy. It will also follow symlinks (on filesystems that support such things) and delete all the files. If you use `aliases`, your files in the aliased paths will not be deleted during undeploy.

Comment: +1, I had the same issue and this fixed it. I'm a bit surprised this isn't more documented. The documentation only says “Please note that setting this to true has some side effects, including the disabling of JSP reloading in a running server: see Bugzilla 37668.” http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation

Comment: I'm having this exact issue, but making my Context look exactly like the example above (minus the antiResourceLocking="true" of course) doesn't have any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing same issue when using tomcat7, my context.xml has this : `<Context> <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource> </Context>` and yet i face the problem. please suggest an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8 - disable caching of static resources:

> context.xml

```
     <Resources cachingAllowed="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution is to replace %TOMCATDIR%/conf/context.xml file content within :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize="1" cacheTTL="1">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```