# Reflecting changes from jsp, css, js, html onto browser without reloading the page

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, dynamic-loading

I have a Dynamic Web Project on eclipse and Tomcat 7 as the server (using within eclipse).

After doing 'Run on Server' on the project, it gets deployed and runs on the browser. However, any changes made to the css/js/html/jsp files do get published automatically on save, however doesn't get reflected on the browser without reload.

Is there any way to make changes visible on the browser without any reload?

Comment: Sounds like a job for scripting (javascript, etc) ?

Comment: Assuming the final production version of the app will have to worry about these kind of changes...which would be unusual.

Comment: I am hitting the same problem, I have to restart the server to see my changes to JS files which is very annoying because it slows down development tremendously

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem appears to be fixed by removing the "antiResourceLocking=true" attribute from the Tomcat "context.xml"  element.

This is consistent with [Tomcat can't see newly created static files and is server-side caching the old files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333462/)

I'm still trying to determine why Eclipse WTP decides to put this attribute in there in some situations and not others.  I have other webapps that are run in Eclipse in the same way and they don't have that attribute set.

Comment: Ok, I figured out why Eclipse WTP decides to use the "antiResourceLocking="true".  It actually doesn't decide, it just uses the "context.xml" from the Tomcat installation files that you point your server at in Eclipse.  I had two different version of Tomcat installed and one had: '<Context>' and the other had '<Context antiResourceLocking="true" antiJARLocking="true" >' in the conf/context.xml.  So the final solution to the problem was to make sure that the Tomcat installation conf/context.xml did NOT have the "antiResourceLocking" attribute set to "true".